# Eclipse errors for all xml files because of its plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

Is there anybody encountering this error? I did not find a proper solution.

Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/.../eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.wst.standard.schemas_1.0.800.v201901071922.jar!/dtds/loose.dtd). For more information, right click 
 on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."

[image: error screenshot]

**My Eclipse:**

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 11.0.1

Comment: Well what does the Show Details in the Problems View say?

Comment: The declaration for the entitiy "HTML.Version" must end with '>'.